# multiple insertion to database on ajax-api request

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am building a social networking site. I have an issue with my `comment-like/dislike` function. Whenever the `like/dislike` button is clicked, the like count updates normally but I get multiple insertions in the `comment_likes/dislikes` table which causes multiple insertions in the notifications table (for all the post ID's). I assume the bug is caused by the jquery ajax calls to the API. Where I'm I going wrong? The below scipts are my profile page javascript and comment_likes api (similar to comment_dislikes). I had even configured the posts and comments api to return the merged JSON posts and comments but didn't work. I need to load each comment below its specific post...The post like/dislike function works fine.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "../api/profile-posts-old?username=<?php echo $_GET['username'];?>",
        processData: false,
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: '',
        success: function(r) {
            var posts = JSON.parse(r);
            $.each(posts, function(index) {
             //load content from db
                $('.timelineposts').html(
                    $('.timelineposts').html() + '<div class="box box-widget"><div class="box-header with-border"><div class="user-block"><img class="img-circle" src="'+posts[index].ProfileImg+'" alt="User Image"><span class="username"><a href="#">'+posts[index].PostedBy+'</a></span><span class="description">Shared publicly - '+posts[index].PostDate+'</span></div><div class="box-tools"><button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="remove"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h"></i></button></div></div><div class="box-body"><p>'+posts[index].PostBody+'</p><ul class="list-inline"><li><a data-id="'+posts[index].PostId+'" href="javascript:void(0)" class="link-black text-sm"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up margin-r-5"></i>'+posts[index].Likes+'</a></li><li><a data-did="'+posts[index].PostId+'" href="javascript:void(0)" class="fixmargin link-black text-sm"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down margin-r-5"></i>'+posts[index].Dislikes+'</a></li><li class="pull-right"><a id=\"nof_com'+posts[index].PostId+'\" href="javascript:void(0)" class="link-black text-sm"><i class="fa fa-comments-o margin-r-5"></i></a></li></ul></div><div id=\"post_com'+posts[index].PostId+'\"></div><div class="box-footer"><form method="post"><img class="img-responsive img-circle img-sm" src="'+posts[index].LogUserImg+'" alt="Alt Text"><div class="input-group img-push"><input type="text" name="postbody" placeholder="Your thoughts? ..." class="form-control '+posts[index].PostId+'"><span class="input-group-btn"><button type="button" data-comid=\"'+posts[index].PostId+'\" class="btn btn-primary btn-flat">Send</button></span></div></form></div></div>'
                );
                //allow users to comment on a post
                $('[data-comid]').click(function() {
                    var buttonid = $(this).attr('data-comid');
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "../api/comments?postid=" + $(this).attr('data-comid'),
                        processData: false,
                        contentType: "application/json",
                        data: '{ "body": "'+ $("."+buttonid).val() +'" }',
                        success: function(r) {
                            location.reload();
                        },
                        error: function(r) {
                            console.log(r);
                        }
                    });
                });
                //get post id to send to comment api
                var buttonid = posts[index].PostId;
                //load comment for every post
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "../api/comments?postid=" + buttonid,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    data: '',
                    success: function(r) {
                        var comments = JSON.parse(r);
                        //
                        $.each(comments, function(index) {
                         //load comments 
                            $('#post_com'+buttonid).html(
                                $('#post_com'+buttonid).html() + '<div class="box-footer box-comments"><div class="box-comment"><img class="img-circle img-sm" src="'+comments[index].ProfileImg+'" alt="User Image"><div class="comment-text"><span class="username">'+comments[index].CommentedBy+'<span class="text-muted pull-right">'+comments[index].CommentDate+'</span></span>'+comments[index].Comment+'<ul class="list-inline"><li><a data-comlid="'+comments[index].ComId+'" href="javascript:void(0)" class="link-black text-sm"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up margin-r-5"></i>'+comments[index].Likes+'</a></li><li><a data-comdid="'+comments[index].ComId+'" href="javascript:void(0)" class="fixmargin link-black text-sm"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down margin-r-5"></i>'+comments[index].Dislikes+'</a></li></ul></div></div></div>'
                            );
                        });
                        //allow users to like comment
                        $('[data-comlid]').click(function() {
                            var buttonid_two = $(this).attr('data-comlid');
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: "../api/comment-likes?comid="+$(this).attr('data-comlid')+"&postid=" + buttonid,
                                processData: false,
                                contentType: "application/json",
                                data: '',
                                success: function(r) {
                                    var res = JSON.parse(r);
                                    $("[data-comlid='"+buttonid_two+"']").html('<i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i> '+res.Likes);
                                    console.log(r);
                                },
                                error: function(r) {
                                    console.log(r);
                                }
                            });
                        });
                        //allow users to dislike comment
                        $('[data-comdid]').click(function() {
                            var buttonid_three = $(this).attr('data-comdid');
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: "../api/comment-dislikes?comid="+$(this).attr('data-comdid')+"&postid=" + buttonid,
                                processData: false,
                                contentType: "application/json",
                                data: '',
                                success: function(r) {
                                    var res = JSON.parse(r);
                                    $("[data-comdid='"+buttonid_three+"']").html('<i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down"></i> '+res.Dislikes);
                                    console.log(r);
                                },
                                error: function(r) {
                                    console.log(r);
                                }
                            });
                        });
                    },
                    error: function(r) {
                        console.log(r);
                    }
                });
                //allow users to like post
                $('[data-id]').click(function() {
                    var buttonid = $(this).attr('data-id');
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "../api/post-likes?id=" + $(this).attr('data-id'),
                        processData: false,
                        contentType: "application/json",
                        data: '',
                        success: function(r) {
                            var res = JSON.parse(r);
                            $("[data-id='"+buttonid+"']").html('<i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i> '+res.Likes);
                            console.log(r);
                        },
                        error: function(r) {
                            console.log(r);
                        }
                    });
                });
                //allow users to dislike post
                $('[data-did]').click(function() {
                    var buttonid = $(this).attr('data-did');
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "../api/post-dislikes?id=" + $(this).attr('data-did'),
                        processData: false,
                        contentType: "application/json",
                        data: '',
                        success: function(r) {
                            var res = JSON.parse(r);
                            $("[data-did='"+buttonid+"']").html('<i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down"></i> '+res.Dislikes);
                            console.log(r);
                        },
                        error: function(r) {
                            console.log(r);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        },
        error: function(r) {
            console.log(r);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
$postId = $_GET['postid'];
$comId = $_GET['comid'];
$token = $_COOKIE['SNID'];
$likerId = $db->query('SELECT user_id FROM login_tokens WHERE token=:token', array(':token'=>sha1($token)))[0]['user_id'];
if (!$db->query('SELECT user_id FROM comment_likes WHERE post_id=:postid AND user_id=:userid AND comment_id=:comid', array(':postid'=>$postId, ':userid'=>$likerId, ':comid'=>$comId))) {
 if (!$db->query('SELECT user_id FROM comment_dislikes WHERE post_id=:postid AND user_id=:userid AND comment_id=:comid', array(':postid'=>$postId, ':userid'=>$likerId, ':comid'=>$comId))) {
   $db->query('UPDATE comments SET likes=likes+1 WHERE id=:comid AND post_id=:postid', array(':comid'=>$comId, ':postid'=>$postId));
   $db->query('INSERT INTO comment_likes VALUES(\'\', :postid, :userid, :comid)', array(':postid'=>$postId, ':userid'=>$likerId, ':comid'=>$comId));
    $temp = $db->query('SELECT comments.user_id AS receiver, comment_likes.user_id AS sender FROM comments, comment_likes WHERE comments.id = comment_likes.comment_id AND comments.id=:comid', array(':comid'=>$comId));
    $r = $temp[0]["receiver"];
    $s = $temp[0]["sender"];
    $db->query('INSERT INTO notifications VALUES (\'\', :type, :receiver, :sender, :post_id, :comid, 0, NOW(), :extra)', array(':type'=>2, ':receiver'=>$r, ':sender'=>$s, ':post_id'=>$postId, ':comid'=>$comId, ':extra'=>""));
 }else {
  die('already liked or disliked comment');
 }
}else {
  $temp = $db->query('SELECT comments.user_id AS receiver, comment_likes.user_id AS sender FROM comments, comment_likes WHERE comments.id = comment_likes.comment_id AND comments.id=:comid', array(':comid'=>$comId));
  $r = $temp[0]["receiver"];
  $s = $temp[0]["sender"];
  $db->query('DELETE FROM notifications WHERE type=2 AND receiver=:receiver AND sender=:sender AND post_id=:postid AND comment_id=:comid', array(':receiver'=>$r, ':sender'=>$s, ':postid'=>$postId, ':comid'=>$comId));
 $db->query('UPDATE comments SET likes=likes-1 WHERE id=:comid AND post_id=:postid', array(':comid'=>$comId, ':postid'=>$postId));
 $db->query('DELETE FROM comment_likes WHERE post_id=:postid AND user_id=:userid AND comment_id=:comid', array(':postid'=>$postId, ':userid'=>$likerId, ':comid'=>$comId));
}
echo "{";
echo '"Likes":';
echo $db->query('SELECT likes FROM comments WHERE id=:comid', array(':comid'=>$comId))[0]['likes'];
echo "}";
```

Comment: I would start by checking whether `comment-likes` php file is called once, and it inserts multiple likes, or it's called multiple times. Then you know where to look for the problem. To do this you need to use the developer tools in your browser, tab 'Network'. See: https://www.browserstack.com/developer-tools

Comment: In general I would like to say that your code does not make for pleasant reading. If the few comments that are there, weren't there, it would be unreadable. I would however have preferred to see some real function's in there to tell me what is what. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions these could also help you to get rid of some of the repetition in the code. I'm also not a huge fan of loading page content through AJAX calls, it usually means a page will be slower to load, but sometimes this can be useful.

Comment: As for the multiple hits: Could it be you create multiple AJAX calls for the same selectors? Given that everything is inside that big `$.each(posts` thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrapped all my AJAX requests in functions and that solved the issue